# How to evaluate equivalent 'samples per second' from Time base value?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, analog, measurement, oscilloscope

The following is from **Tek DSO manual** about the Time base and sample rates.

[image: Time scaling parameters - Tek DSO]

**When i turn the knob further, i am able to read values like M 100ms or M 250ms.
What woud these evaluate to in terms of 'Samples/second'?**

I am looking for how this computation from scaling parameter to Samp/s is done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Many scopes have different memory depth settings, but ignoring that possibility..

Assuming 10 divisions (pretty typical) it appears that your scope has a memory of 2500 points.  Therefore the sampling rate is 2500 / (10 * time per division).  For example, at 5 us / div the rate is 2500 / (10 * 5u) = 50 MSa/s.  And at 100 us / div, the rate is 2500 / 1000u = 2.5 MSa/s.  See?

So at 100 ms per division, the rate would be 2500 / 1000m = 2.5 kSa/s and at 250 ms per division 1 kSa/s.